# To get the row of a table by clicking on a link in it, using jQuery

Tags: jquery, html

I have table in which rows are added dynamically on click of button.

```
 function SaveData()
  {
   var empid='CT'+($("#Employee tbody tr").length+1);
   var newRow = jQuery('<tr><td>'+empid+' </td><td>'+$("#name").val()+'</td><td>'+$("#desg").val()+'</td><td>'+$("#Sal").val()+' </td><td><a href="#" class="Edit_link" onclick="EditRow();">Edit</a>&nbsp &nbsp<a href="#">Delete</a> </td></tr>');
jQuery('#Employee').append(newRow); 

 }
```

So the created table looks like:

```
Id   Name  Designation  Salary

1    ABC   XYZ          10000    Edit  Delete  
2    ABC   XYZ          10000    Edit  Delete
```

Now whenever I want to edit the specific row I will click on Edit button of that row.

```
  function EditRow()
        {   
            var row= $(this).closest('tr');  
            var id=$("td:eq(0)",row).text(); 
            var name=$("td:eq(1)",row).text(); 
            var desg=$("td:eq(2)",row).text(); 
            alert(id);  
            alert(name);  
            alert(desg);  
        }
```

Here in alert box it shows blank values for id,name,desg.

Comment: provide a jsfiddle to work with

Comment: What you want the row number of the row in which the edit button is present??

Comment: Row number and its values in variables so that i can edit it and save it back.

Comment: each row, or button could have a unique id/name that refers to *this* particular row of data.

Comment: Id is unique for each row.

Comment: then you need to use it on the button somehow - As Milind suggest could be one way to do this.

Comment: @Harabati You can check my answer now. It is working fine.

Answer (score 0):

pass current dom using `this` when calling `EditRow()` .like this:

```
 onclick="EditRow(this);"
```

And to get current row in `EditRow`,  use:

```
$(this).closest('tr');//this would give you current row object
$(this).find('td').slice(0,3).each(function(){
     alert($(this).text());// will alert name,designation,salary 1 by 1
})
```

Comment: How to access its cells(td).

Comment: which td you want. The parent td of a tag??

Comment: Milind, It doesnt work...object of 'tr' is not passed to the row variable.  hence it shows blank alert boxes for td.

Comment: You have not passed argument in function `EditRow()` it should be `function EditRow(this){`

Answer (score 0):

You can get the row like this:

```
var row=$(this).closest("tr");
```

after finding the row you can find the value of it's td like below and go forward for your save:

```
     $(document).on('click','.Edit_link',function(){
        var row=$(this).closest("tr");
        var id=$("td:eq(0)",row).text()
      })
```

Answer (score 0):

Append the data table to id Document_Datatable. Onclick of pencil, you can edit a particular row.
var ROOT = '@Url.Content("~/")';
response is the function parameter in ajax success.

```
var table = $('#Document_Datatable').DataTable();    
table.clear().draw();
for (var i = 0; i < response.length; i++) {
var edit = "<a onclick='getSingleDocument(" + response[i].WCNDocumentId + ',' + 
response[i].WCNID + ")' title'Edit' class='btn btn-xs btn-default -text-blue' data- 
target='#UploadDocument' data-toggle='modal'><i class='fa fa-pencil'></i></a> <label 
title='Delete'  class='btn btn-xs btn-danger' onclick='DeleteDoc(" + 
response[i].WCNDocumentId + ',"' + response[i].FileName + '"' + ")'  data- 
toggle='modal' ><i class='fa fa-trash-o'></i></label>";
var name = 'Test';
DocID = response[i].WCNDocumentId;
DocName = response[i].DocumentName;
var roNode = table.row.add([
response[i].DocumentName,
response[i].Description,
response[i].Description,
response[i].UserName,
edit
])
table.draw();
```